# how can I find execution time of multi threaded application

Tags: java, multithreading

After execution of below code I am getting time as 0 , because time calculation is present in main thread and it is calculating durationTime value and then executing threadPool.

I wants to find total time taken while executing threads.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime(); 
        int numberThread=10;
        String apiToBeCall="abcApi";

        Runnable r1=new SFSrmMainClass(apiToBeCall);

        ExecutorService threadPool=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberThread);
        for (int i=0;i<numberThread;i++)
        {

            threadPool.execute(r1);
        }
        threadPool.shutdown();

        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
         long durationTime = (endTime - startTime); 
        System.out.println("time for "+apiToBeCall +" is having thread="+numberThread +" is "+durationTime/1000000000);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [awaitTermination](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) after calling shutdown(), which blocks the main thread until all threads finished.

Example:

```
static long measureTasks(final int nThreads, final Runnable... tasks) 
    throws InterruptedException
{
    final ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);
    final long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    for (Runnable task : tasks)
        pool.execute(task);

    pool.shutdown();
    pool.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    return System.nanoTime() - startTime;
}
```

Comment: for using awaitTermination I need to give parameter "time" , as if execution of threads took more than 10seconds , will it give time as 10 seconds or returns more than 10seconds

Comment: @NiteshBagri "Blocks until all tasks have completed execution after a shutdown request, or the timeout occurs, or the current thread is interrupted, whichever happens first. ....     true if this executor terminated and false if the timeout elapsed before termination" If it times out before the threads finish, awaitTermination returns false.